# Unable to resolve host in Ubuntu using sudo

Tags: sudo

I am trying to use sudo to update, and get a strange reply for terminal:

```
sergio@sem:~$ sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo: unable to resolve host sem
```

I suspect this could be a hacking of the host, how can I correct this?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that `/etc/hostname` is just the name of your computer and that `/etc/hosts` has entry for `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04.

It is not evidence of being hacked.

I solved the problem by adding my hostname to the line containing "127.0.1.1" in the "/etc/hosts" file and then issued "/etc/init.d/hostname.sh start"